# Unable to have different icons for taskbar and window bar?

Tags: c++, winapi, resources, icons, registerclass

I have two icons (.ico files). A big 32x32 one and another small 16x16.

[image]

I'm trying to set the `hIcon` of my `WNDCLASSEX` to be the big one, and `hIconSm` to the smaller one. Yet I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do that! I first tried `LoadIcon`:

```
wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SKELETON));
wndclass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SKELETON_SM));
```

It always loads the same icon for both the top window bar and the taskbar. Same thing with `LoadImage`.

[image]

Here's all the codes:

Resource.h

```
#define IDI_SKELETON 1000
#define IDI_SKELETON_SM 1001
```

Skeleton.rc

```
#include "Resource.h"

IDI_SKELETON       ICON "Skeleton.ico"
IDI_SKELETON_SM    ICON "Skeleton_sm.ico"
```

WinMain.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "Resource.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK
HandleEvent(HWND   window,
            UINT   message,
            WPARAM wparam,
            LPARAM lparam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC dc;
            RECT rect;

            dc = BeginPaint(window, &ps);
            GetClientRect(window, &rect);
            DrawText(dc, TEXT("This is a test window"), -1, &rect,
                         DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
            EndPaint(window, &ps);
        }
        break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(window, message, wparam, lparam);
}

int CALLBACK
WinMain(HINSTANCE instance,
        HINSTANCE previous,
        LPSTR     cmd,
        int       cmdshow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wndclass;
    TCHAR classname[] = TEXT("24HoursClass");

    wndclass.cbSize = sizeof(wndclass);
    wndclass.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = HandleEvent;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = instance;
    wndclass.hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SKELETON), IMAGE_ICON,
             GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON), 0);
    wndclass.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SKELETON_SM), IMAGE_ICON,
             GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON), 0);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = classname;

    RegisterClassEx(&wndclass);

    HWND window = CreateWindowA(classname, "24 Hours",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            0, 0, instance, 0);

    MSG msg;

    while(GetMessage(&msg, window, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Clearly, icons in both places are of the same size - the small one. Why do you expect a big icon to be used where there's no space for it?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. "Clearly, icons in both places are of the same size - the small one" - Could you elaborate?

Comment: Both on the taskbar, and on the window title, the space available for the icon is 16x16, as is evident from your very own screenshot.

Comment: I did not think of that, thanks! Going Right Click on Taskbar and unchecking Use Small Icons fixed it! Convert to answer if you want.

Comment: Although it's still weird. If I use `LoadIcon` to load the 32x32 icons in both places it works! According to what you said there should be no space for it. Does Windows scale it down, or how does this work?

Comment: Yes Windows scales it down, when it has no other choice.